# Converting some pages to be rendered on the server side in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, server-side

I wonder how to convert only two pages in a Vue3 project to be rendered on the server-side to enhance their SEO. I also want to avoid migrating to Nuxt.js.

Thanks for your help in advance.

I tried using Node.js configs according to Vue3's documentation but it can only accept a stringified Vue root component.

https://staging-cf.vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#ssr-vs-ssg

Comment: The question is too unspecific for SO. There's more than just Nuxt, it's unknown what's your setup but Vite SSR is less opinionated and works well with Vite, https://staging-cf.vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#vite-ssr . You can't just import .vue sfc files in node server without a build tool because it's not valid JS

Answer (score 1):

### No, this is not possible with Vue3 alone

You'll either need a

#### Static site generator

This is not possible with only Vue3 - It's just not supposed to be a static site generator (such as [VitePress](https://vitepress.vuejs.org/), as suggested in your link).

**or**

#### Server side generated pages

You'll need something like what you already suggested - Nuxt.Js or similar.
It features something called [pre-rendered routes](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/commands/generate) and a `generate` command. Similar to [Nuxt2 exclude](https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#exclude) and running `nuxt generate`.

Nuxt will pre-render some routes while other will only be available through SSR.